# How can we add dropdown like html on click of fullcalendar-angular CustomButton

Tags: angular9, fullcalendar-5

I am working on fullcalendar-angular component where in I have a custom button called filter, on click of it the modal/dialog/menu-items should open just like dropdown. So how do we implement this under customButton click function? is there a way to add HTML and how? as shown in image.

```
calendarOptions:CalendarOptions = {
        initialView:'dayGridMonth',
        themeSystem:'bootstrap',
        nowIndicator:true,
        //showNonCurrentDates:false,
        fixedWeekCount:false,
        customButtons:{
            myCustomBtton: {
                bootstrapFontAwesome:'fas fa-sliders-h',
                click: function(click,element){
                    //how do i add the code here`enter code here`
                },
            },
        },
        headerToolbar:{
            left:'prev,next today',
            center:'title',
            right:'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay,listMonth myCustomBtton'
        },
```

[fullcalendar-angualr custombutton image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRJX0.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a novice at Angular, but I was able to create a dropdown by just injecting some HTML for a dropdown via a function called after the eventDidMount hook.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks

I'm happy to give you some sample CSS/JS to show hide the dropdown, too if it's useful to you.